# React - Create connected provider arround default provider, that will take data from store and pass it as props to default provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, wrapper, connect, provider

Assume I use desired provider in my app, let name it `MyProvider` and wrapp my app with it. And that provider must take `data1` and `data2` as props:

```js
const data1 = store.getState().data1;
const data2 = "some data";

<Provider store={store}>
    <Myprovider data1={data1} data2={data2}>
        <App/>
    </Myprovider>
</ Provider>
```

So `data1` is retrieved from state, and data2 is predefined data. When `data1` is changed (I mean when some actions are dispatched and some changes on `state's data1` happen, provider doesn't detect it).
So what comes to my mind is to create `wrapper for Myprovider`, lets call it `ConnectedMyprovider` that will be connected to redux store, and will pass `data1` and `data2` to `Myprovider` as props.

Code for `ConnectedMyprovider` would be something like:

```js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {MyProvider} from 'MyProvider';

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const {data1} = state.data1;
    const data2 = ownProps.data2;

    return {data1: data1, data2: data2};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyProvider);
```

And then, wrapping my app becomes as:

```js
const data2 = "some data";
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedMyProvider data2={data2}>
    <App/>
  </ConnectedMyProvider>
</ Provider>
```

It ends up with error `Make sure your <MyProvider> is set up correctly.`  No `data2` provided. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

@Vilva.
I moved it directly into `ConnectedMyProvider` and added this part `class ConnectedMyProvider extends Component {`:

```js
 import {Provider as TranslateProvider} from 'react-translated'; // this is provider I wrapped

    class ConnectedMyProvider extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <TranslateProvider language={this.props.language} translation={translation} >
                    <App/>
                </TranslateProvider>
            );
        }
    }

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        language: state.language
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ConnectedMyProvider);
```

I defined `ConnectedMyProvider` as new Component and returned `Provider` (wrapped provider) in render function. Note that I put also `<App/>` in return statement. And then, in index I have `ConnectedMyProvider` as last child in render method:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedMyProvider />
  </ Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As I mentioned above, `<App/>` is nested in `ConnectedMyProvider` return statement, it doesn't work if I nest it in `index.jsx's` render function, inside `<ConnectedMyProvider>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Its been some time since I used redux but your approach seems fairly correct to me. Are you sure there are no naming/syntax errors? The logic sounds good.

Try checking that `ownProps.data2`is indeed working. If not, it might sound like a stupid suggestion, but why not setting data2 directly on ConnectedMyProvider?.